# How to use React app inside Perspective in Bloomreach?

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, hippocms

We are using Bloomreach Experience (Hippo CMS) in our development and need to integrate exsiting react app into Perspective inside CMS panel. Is there any way to do this, exclude using iFrame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To integrate the React app in the CMS channel manager, the app should use the React SDK to render some specific comments HTML elements meant for previewing and editing capabilities.

Next, a proxy should be installed so the channel manager requests a app/channel on the same host, which is proxied to where is actually lives.

Please start at https://documentation.bloomreach.com/library/concepts/spa-integration/introduction.html

HTH
Jeroen

Answer (score 0):

React app can be easily integrated into other apps. You need to add a container element inside your existing DOM for react app to render. Then load the built React app using the script tag

Comment: Yeah, but most of the time it is probably a bit more complicated than that, as there are some JS, CSS or even image assets that need to be uploaded, linked and correctly loaded too, right?

Answer (score 0):

So, here is a solution:
We should add  `"homepage": "./."` to `package.json`.
Then, important thing that you shouldn't do is using `BrowserRouter`. Use instead `HashRouter`. 
Build your app and use this files in Perspective like other HTML, CSS and JS files.